# IIS7 parse error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing, iis-7

I just put all my aspx files on the local folder and made a website in IIS7. I added a virtual directory to it and then converted the virtual directory to application. The website loads properly but when i click the link that calls my application i get this error message.

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'XXXX.xxxx'.

The error line in code is this -

> Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="VB" Inherits="_XXXX.xxxx" Codebehind="XXX.xx.vb" %>

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also deployed your bin folder with the compiled dlls?

Take a look at [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(VS.80).aspx) for a guide on how to publish an asp.net site.